# Can you configure SQL Server 2008 Auditing to keep the audit data on a database other than the one being audited?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, auditing, audit-trail

We are planning on using the new auditing feature in SQL Server 2008. Is there a way to configure the auditing component to insert audit data to a separate database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so. It's to-file (rolling log) or to event viewer. This is a good reference: http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=133